# separate thread to change label icon

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timertask

I want to use a separate thread for changing a label's icon every 2 seconds.The icons (pictures actually, reclama1, reclama2, etc) are stored in the project's folder called "poze".
So when i try the code below, I receive the following error every 2 seconds.
What am I doing wrong?

error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type:<any>
```

code:

```
public GUI() {
    initComponents();
    JTable.setModel(m);     
    JTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
    bFiltru.setVisible(false);
    bFiltru.setText("Afiseaza intreaga lista");

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
    public void run(){
    for (int i=1; i<5, i++){
    ImageIcon iconLogo = new ImageIcon("poze/reclama"+i+".gif");
    jLabelReclama.setIcon(iconLogo);
    if (i == 4) i = 0;
    }
    }
}
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(task, 0, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use a Swing Timer not a java.util.Timer as that's what it's for -- to give you timer functionality but *on* the Swing event thread.
2. Your code, even if it worked would not do anything near what you desire as your for loop would loop *immediately*.
3. You shouldn't be using a for loop at all. The Timer provides your looping functionality. Increment a counter in the timer and use its value to get the next icon. Set the counter to 0 when it reaches the size of the collection.
4. What line causes your error, because it has nothing to do with the problem you describe.

Comment: 1. If I use a Swing Timer will the label icon change if the app is already doing something that takes long time?
2. I wasn't very happy with the loop either, but I was focusing more on the error
3. the line is for (int i=1; i<5, i++){

Comment: @bluesony: it darn well better. Any long-running process should be done off of the EDT, so this will not be a problem in a well-constructed program. This is not an issue with a Swing Timer since the timing function is done invisibly and off of the EDT, while the code in the Timer's ActionListener is done *on* the EDT. Again, just use the Swing Timer.

Comment: you were perfectly right: I shouldn't be using a for loop at all.
I managed to make it work with Swing Timer but also with Util Timer.
Thanks again

Comment: The code with Util Timer that worked:
TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
        private int i = 0;
        public void run(){
        ImageIcon iconLogo = new ImageIcon("poze/reclama"+ i++ +".gif");
        jLabelReclama.setIcon(iconLogo);
        if (i == 4) i = 1;
        }
        }
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(task, 0, 2000);